# Expandable items in recyclerview not expanding in last item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an expandable view inside some items in recyclerview.
Everything is Ok but if expanding item is last item and list is scrollable it does not expand correctly and just expands a little, for example, it supposed to expand 100dp but just expanded 10dp!
This Problem occurs just in the last item and just if items are scrollable(not when there is one or two item and the list is not scrollable)

Answer (score 1):

Try giving bottom padding in list item layout